# Correct way to ensure single instance and pass on arguments for Windows c++ console application

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application

I’m writing a simple Windows console c++ application. If the application is started a second time (on the same computer) it should not span an new instance but pass command line arguments to the instance already running.

I have accomplished to ensure that the application only runs in one instance by using mutex but I am unable to notify the first application that it has been started as second time and pass on command line arguments.

Use case:
`listener.exe -start` // starts listener
`listener.exe -stop` // stops listener

Comment: You're probably looking for inter-process communication, IPC.

Comment: Yes, use IPC as mentioned below in answers there is no implicit support with command interpreter that would again invoke the main of the same running executable. Otherwise IPC with named global event is easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first listener should wait on an event object which is for shutdown. When you launch `listener.exe -stop` then it will just set the global event for shutdown and if first instance is running then it would exit. Named event object is required in order for the other processes to refer it. Also when you fire command 2nd time it will launch another process there is no implicit IPC with command interpreter.

listener.exe -start:

1. Create a named event (CreateEvent)
2. Wait on the event in the main thread or any suitable thread. (WaitForSingleObject)
3. On event initiate shutdown

listener.exe -stop

1. Get Handle to named event.
2. Set the event so that the thread of first process knows that shutdown event is fired and it exits

Some reference:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to communicate a simple boolean value (start/stop, for example), then you probably need an [Event object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to exchange more complex data between processes, you could use [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or perhaps blocks of shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of IPC.  One technique that worked well for me on Windows was using a separate thread to process messages for a message only window.  Once you determine you are the primary instance of the program, or listener(via mutex creation as in your scenario) create the message only window and start a thread to process messages.  For secondary instances, if there is something on the command tail, pass it as a string to the message only window using WM_COPYDATA message.  The listener program ignores all other messages except perhaps a token telling it to quit.  Once the secondary instance passes the message to the message only window it exits.

This can work very well for a scenario where you may have dozens of secondary instances opening.  One example would be the user selects 50 files in an Explorer folder, right clicks, and runs the program.  The listener processes the message only window in a dedicated thread and queues up the strings(in this case filenames) for processing.